# BufferRegion is cleared by a call to clf()

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have an application in which I'd like to draw counties from a shapefile using Basemap.  Drawing the county polygons is the bottleneck in the rendering, and since I'll be drawing the same region of the US (a bunch of times), I'd rather not have to draw all the polygons any more than I need to.  So I had the idea to draw the counties to a figure with a transparent background, copy the axes to a pixel buffer using `copy_from_bbox()`, and restore the buffer using `restore_region()` when I need to draw the counties.

The basic code goes like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map = Basemap(...) # Create Basemap object

map.readshapefile("countyp020", 'counties', linewidth=0.5) # Draws the county lines
plt.gcf().patch.set_alpha(0.0)
plt.gca().patch.set_alpha(0.0)

# Copy to the pixel buffer (county_buffer is of type BufferRegion)
county_buffer = plt.gcf().canvas.copy_from_bbox(plt.gca().bbox)

plt.clf() # This line is problematic (see below)

# Plot my data here ...

# Restore the pixel buffer
plt.gcf().canvas.restore_region(county_buffer)
plt.gcf().canvas.blit(plt.gca().bbox) # Not sure if this line is necessary

plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

It works like a charm ... except for the line where I clear the figure.  Clearing the figure between renderings apparently clears the BufferRegion object as well, and since I update the title and colorbar, I'd also like to clear the figure between renderings.

So my question is does anybody know a way to clear the figure and keep the pixel buffer intact?  I haven't been able to find much documentation on `BufferRegion`, `copy_from_bbox()`, or `restore_region()`, so it's been a bit difficult to debug this.  If there's no easy way around it, then does anybody know another way to do basically what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a similar kind of question from the matplotlib users list: http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg23317.html

Comment: Interestingly, `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy` will not copy `BufferRegion` objects....

Comment: Did you ever find a reasonable work-around to this?

Comment: Well, I don't think I ever found a code-based work-around.  The program was to hand-place vortex centers in a bunch of plots, which was sort of a one-off operation. Since I had ~4500 of them, I was trying to reduce the strain on myself by having them render as quickly as possible.  I think I just lived with the extra delay in rendering, since it was a one-off operation.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Why is this tagged with `tkinter`?